# editing a string in bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a bat file that reads a list of records and extract a number from each line. It then writes these numbers to another text file and from here it is calculated to see what the total value was, dropping the leading 0's as it reads the numbers.

This all works fine, but what I can't seem to get right is as this value is a price it needs to have 2 decimal points. At the moment it prints to file as `2971480`, but I need it as `29714.80`. Is there a way to do this in a bat file?

The code I'm using is the following:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem.> "C:\output.txt"
for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /L "T" "C:\test files\test.txt"') do (
set "LINE=%%L" & set "LINE=!LINE:*ResponseCode=!" & echo !LINE:~39,8%!
)>> "C:\output.txt"
endlocal
set sum=0
cd C:\test files
for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%A in (output.txt) do set /a sum=sum+%%A
echo The total Sales for today was %sum% > output2.txt
output2.txt
pause
```

I honestly don't know where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**

The original file looks like this:

> "59",003005213,23,10,0017,07,59,0000,0000,03,03005213,04,0000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,"R",00000000
>   "59",002009205,23,10,0017,08,00,0001,0000,02,02009205,02,0001,00000000,00004300,00000000,00004300,00005000,00005000,00000000,00000000,00000700,"R",00000000
>   "61",0000000001879,00000010,1,00000430,00004300,02,01,0,"T",002009205,0
>   "59",002009206,23,10,0017,08,02,0001,0000,02,02009206,02,0001,00000000,00001200,00000000,00001200,00001200,00001200,00000000,00000000,00000000,"R",00000000
>   "61",0000000001430,00000001,1,00001200,00001200,02,01,0,"T",002009206,0
>   "59",003005214,23,10,0017,08,03,0001,0000,03,03005214,02,0001,00000000,00006500,00000000,00006500,00006500,00006500,00000000,00000000,00000000,"R",00000000
>   "61",0000000001428,00000005,1,00001300,00006500,02,01,0,"T",003005214,0
>   "59",002009207,23,10,0017,08,04,0002,0000,02,02009207,02,0002,00003600,00000000,00000000,00003600,00005000,00005000,00000000,00000000,00001400,"R",00000000
>   "61",0000000000285,00000001,1,00002800,00002800,02,00,0,"T",002009207,0
>   "61",0000000000430,00000002,1,00000400,00000800,02,00,0,"T",002009207,0
>   "59",003005215,23,10,0017,08,07,0000,0000,03,03005215,04,0000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,"R",00000000
>   "59",003005216,23,10,0017,08,09,0000,0000,03,03005216,04,0000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,"R",00000000
>   "59",002009208,23,10,0017,08,10,0001,0000,02,02009208,02,0001,00007000,00000000,00000000,00007000,00010000,00010000,00000000,00000000,00003000,"R",00000000
>   "61",0000000000337,00000001,1,00007000,00007000,02,00,0,"T",002009208,0
>   "59",003005217,23,10,0017,08,10,0001,0000,03,03005217,02,0001,00000000,00006500,00000000,00006500,00006500,00006500,00000000,00000000,00000000,"R",00000000
>   "61",0000000001428,00000005,1,00001300,00006500,02,01,0,"T",003005217,0

Each line either starting with a 61 or 59.

Then after the filter:

> 00004300
>   00001200
>   00006500
>   00002800
>   00000800
>   00007000
>   00006500
>   00002900
>   00000400
>   00003250
>   00000520
>   00002990
>   00003250
>   00001300
>   00005040
>   00000470
>   00000410
>   00002600
>   00017000
>   00002800
>   00001575
>   00006500
>   00002430
>   00001615
>   00002150
>   00000350
>   00001300
>   00001435
>   00006500
>   00002600
>   00003250
>   00001860
>   00003250
>   00002985
>   00000430
>   00001200
>   00000860
>   00000515
>   00002350
>   00001300
>   00001300
>   00001005
>   00000865
>   00000430
>   00002200
>   00006500
>   00002490
>   00001985
>   00001300
>   00013000
>   00001300
>   00006500
>   00001300
>   00006500
>   00006500
>   00001300
>   00003250
>   00003925
>   00001160
>   00002800
>   00006500
>   00002200
>   00001300
>   00000430
>   00003250
>   00000615
>   00013000
>   00005490
>   00002600
>   00002510
>   00001300
>   00008445
>   00003250
>   00004595
>   00013000
>   00001000
>   00001005
>   00001300
>   00006500
>   00001300
>   00001300
>   00003255
>   00000670
>   00002600
>   00004400
>   00002480
>   00001490
>   00001950
>   00002895
>   00003120
>   00003525
>   00003250
>   00005660
>   00013000
>   00001470
>   00006500
>   00010810
>   00003250
>   00003870
>   00000550
>   00000400
>   00001460
>   00003250
>   00001300
>   00000430
>   00003250
>   00000430
>   00007000
>   00007165
>   00026000
>   00003250
>   00002445
>   00006500
>   00003890
>   00003390
>   00003250
>   00002800
>   00002395
>   00005555
>   00002970
>   00002700
>   00003445
>   00003150
>   00001520
>   00000930
>   00010205
>   00002945
>   00003250
>   00001120
>   00006500
>   00001215
>   00006500
>   00001980
>   00001495
>   00002040
>   00000400
>   00003250
>   00000220
>   00006500
>   00003250
>   00006140
>   00002600
>   00009750
>   00000525
>   00002405
>   00001920
>   00000995
>   00000430
>   00000430
>   00006500
>   00001965
>   00006500
>   00001070
>   00000810
>   00000430
>   00017000
>   00000485
>   00002010
>   00006500
>   00001105
>   00003480
>   00003250
>   00003250
>   00010025
>   00000510
>   00003250
>   00007000
>   00003250
>   00002320
>   00006500
>   00002600
>   00000650
>   00010345
>   00005340
>   00002995
>   00001240
>   00003250
>   00001005
>   00006500
>   00001015
>   00003250
>   00005065
>   00000430
>   00000580
>   00000450
>   00000860
>   00004550
>   00000430
>   00001300
>   00010560
>   00000880
>   00000465
>   00006500
>   00000840
>   00003250
>   00006060
>   00002600
>   00010625
>   00003250
>   00000430
>   00000920
>   00000930
>   00002600
>   00005245
>   00001300

I then add them together dropping the leading zeros to get my final total.

Comment: Can you show an example input file too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo The total Sales for today was %sum:~0,-2%.%sum:~-2% > output2.txt
```

That is, output `sum`, except for the last 2 characters and a dot and then the last 2 characters.

Comment: When I run this my output prints %sum:0,-2%.%sum:~-2% instead of the number

Comment: I missed out a `~`.